# How to get pattern between first occurrence of two characters in R?

Tags: regex, r, pattern-matching

I am trying to match a pattern: anything that is between `VD=` and the first occurrence of `|` from a character string, say `tmp`, like this:

```
tmp <- "PC=I;RS=128850544;RE=128850566;LEN=6;S1=36;S2=499.417;REP=2;VT=Ins;VD=SMO|CCDS5811.1|r.?|-|-|protein_coding:CDS:intron:insertion:intron_variant|SO:0000010:SO:0000316:SO:0000188:SO:0000667:SO:0001627;VC=intronic;VW=SMO|CCDS5811.1|r.?|-|-|protein_coding:CDS:intron:insertion:intron_variant|SO:0000010:SO:0000316:SO:0000188:SO:0000667:SO:0001627"

gene <- sub("^.*VD=([A-Za-z0-9]+)[|].*", "\\1", tmp)
gene
# [1] "SMO"
```

But when there is no `VD=` or `|` in the string, it grabs the whole string:

```
tmp <- "PC=D;RS=72450731;RE=72450735;LEN=1;S1=72;S2=802.939;REP=3;VT=Del"

gene <- sub("^.*VD=([A-Za-z0-9]+)[|].*", "\\1", tmp)
gene
# [1] "PC=D;RS=72450731;RE=72450735;LEN=1;S1=72;S2=802.939;REP=3;VT=Del"
```

I don't understand why it is grabbing the whole string instead of `NA` even when there are no `VD=` or `|` characters present. Is there a way to grab a pattern between the first occurrence of two characters and print it or print NA if the pattern is not found.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: first `match` and then `grab`

Comment: `sub`/`gsub` don't grab anything, they **substitute**, and there is nothing in your 2nd case **to** substitute

Comment: use `regmatches/regexpr` or better yet use `stringr::str_extract` or friends

Comment: to answer your question, `^.*VD=([A-Za-z0-9]+)[|].*$|.` would give you your desired results for both although I like the more simple regex by @noob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex seems quite complicated for the task. Using simple regex like this

**Regex:** `VD=([^|]+)` would be sufficient. Use `\\1` to back-reference.

**Explanation:** `([^|]+)` matches anything from `VD=` until first `|` is encountered.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW5bJ1/1)**

```
tmp <- c("PC=D;RS=72450731;RE=72450735;LEN=1;S1=72;S2=802.939;REP=3;VT=Del", "PC=I;RS=128850544;RE=128850566;LEN=6;S1=36;S2=499.417;REP=2;VT=Ins;VD=SMO|CCDS5811.1|r.?|-|-|protein_coding:CDS:intron:insertion:intron_variant|SO:0000010:SO:0000316:SO:0000188:SO:0000667:SO:0001627;VC=intronic;VW=SMO|CCDS5811.1|r.?|-|-|protein_coding:CDS:intron:insertion:intron_variant|SO:0000010:SO:0000316:SO:0000188:SO:0000667:SO:0001627")
gsub('VD=([^|]+)|.', '\\1', tmp)
# [1] ""    "SMO"
```

Comment: `Op's` concern was not about regex though

Comment: what exactly makes you think that OP doesn't have the regex they want? this does smth *different* from OP, and is not just a simplification

Comment: @rock321987: Yes but OP used quite complicated way to achieve that task and I am suggesting a simplified version. Just being helpful. If only purpose was t provide direct solution then Only one solution for each question will be truly **Helpful** rendering all other useless.

Comment: agree that regex is complicated.

Comment: Take a look at this regex `^.*VD=([A-Za-z0-9]+)[|].*` . There is no need to start matching from beginning. There is not need to match all characters ( using `.*` ) and reach `VD=`.

Comment: @rawr: Yes it is. But does it mean that anything other than **complete solution** that might be **helpful** should not be laid out ?

Comment: @rawr: Thanks for the edit. I hope it's right as I am not into `R` yet.

Comment: I don't have a problem with your answer, I think it is better than the complicated regex. my point was that this is an r/regex tagged question and should be answered as such. you would not answer a javascript flavor question with a python flavor, correct?

Comment: @rawr: True that ! But you see am just getting into programming and stuff. Am learning and helping the best I could.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're effectively trying to parse a multilevel delimited string. I recommend not trying to use a single regex to extract the information you want, but rather using a more rigorous stepwise breakdown of the elements of the syntax.

First, you can split on semicolon to get the top-level pieces that look like variable assignments:

```
tmp <- 'PC=I;RS=128850544;RE=128850566;LEN=6;S1=36;S2=499.417;REP=2;VT=Ins;VD=SMO|CCDS5811.1|r.?|-|-|protein_coding:CDS:intron:insertion:intron_variant|SO:0000010:SO:0000316:SO:0000188:SO:0000667:SO:0001627;VC=intronic;VW=SMO|CCDS5811.1|r.?|-|-|protein_coding:CDS:intron:insertion:intron_variant|SO:0000010:SO:0000316:SO:0000188:SO:0000667:SO:0001627';
specs <- strsplit(fixed=T,tmp,';')[[1L]];
specs;
##  [1] "PC=I"
##  [2] "RS=128850544"
##  [3] "RE=128850566"
##  [4] "LEN=6"
##  [5] "S1=36"
##  [6] "S2=499.417"
##  [7] "REP=2"
##  [8] "VT=Ins"
##  [9] "VD=SMO|CCDS5811.1|r.?|-|-|protein_coding:CDS:intron:insertion:intron_variant|SO:0000010:SO:0000316:SO:0000188:SO:0000667:SO:0001627"
## [10] "VC=intronic"
## [11] "VW=SMO|CCDS5811.1|r.?|-|-|protein_coding:CDS:intron:insertion:intron_variant|SO:0000010:SO:0000316:SO:0000188:SO:0000667:SO:0001627"
```

Next you can search for the LHS of interest, extracting just the first occurrence (in case there are multiple matches):

```
vdspec <- grep(perl=T,value=T,'^VD=',specs)[1L];
vdspec;
## [1] "VD=SMO|CCDS5811.1|r.?|-|-|protein_coding:CDS:intron:insertion:intron_variant|SO:0000010:SO:0000316:SO:0000188:SO:0000667:SO:0001627"
```

You can drill down into the RHS and then split that into the pipe-delimited fields:

```
vd <- sub(perl=T,'^VD=','',vdspec);
vd;
## [1] "SMO|CCDS5811.1|r.?|-|-|protein_coding:CDS:intron:insertion:intron_variant|SO:0000010:SO:0000316:SO:0000188:SO:0000667:SO:0001627"
vdfields <- strsplit(fixed=T,vd,'|')[[1L]];
vdfields;
## [1] "SMO"
## [2] "CCDS5811.1"
## [3] "r.?"
## [4] "-"
## [5] "-"
## [6] "protein_coding:CDS:intron:insertion:intron_variant"
## [7] "SO:0000010:SO:0000316:SO:0000188:SO:0000667:SO:0001627"
```

Now you can easily get the value you're looking for:

```
vdfields[1L];
## [1] "SMO"
```

If your target LHS does not match, you'll get `NA` from the `grep()[1L]` call:

```
xxspec <- grep(perl=T,value=T,'^XX=',specs)[1L];
xxspec;
## [1] NA
```

Thus you can branch on the result of the `grep()[1L]` call to handle the case of a missing LHS.